# What is easiest way to save mms to pc?

Tags: iphone, android, windows-mobile, blackberry, symbian

I want to save received mms in my PC through a data cable or Bluetooth automatically.

Can any one guide me to a phone which supports this functionality or is there any specific software available to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Care to share what model/type of phone you are using?

Comment: it could be any depends upon your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Basically there are four ways to achieve this:

1. As you mentioned: Using a data cable / Bluetooth connection. Some phones won't allow you to send a MMS via Bluetooth - and by using a data cable you cannot access the whole phone memory, mostly. For some phones (eg. Samsung F480), you can find an alternative software with which you can access the whole internal memory. Maybe you can access your messages there. As those tools are phone specific, I cannot tell you a link / programm. You might want to consult Google and co.
2. Most providers allow you to access your MMS from within a web interface. Be aware that some will send you the required links only, if they think, that you can't recieve MMS with your cell phone. So be careful, if you want to be able to read those messages on your cell phone, too. In future you might only get a SMS containing a link to their web interfaces instead of a MMS
3. As a variant to 2: Some providers will send you your MMS as eMail. But there might be the same problems, as in 2.
4. You tagged with Android / iPhone /...: "Maybe there's an app for it" :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have a BlackBerry Storm and I received MMS a while ago. What I've done is, since I'm with Telus (Canada), they have a website for Telus Mobility client and you can get your MMS from this website. So then, you save it onto your computer. Maybe your provider has the same thing. Give them a call!

Also, you can also try to connect your cellphone to you computer and then try to retreive the MMS from your PC. Not sure which cell you have since you tagged 3-4 different cell phones.

I wish you the best of luck with that!

Comment: no, in my country no service like this exists.